# Adaptec 5405: can't disable background consistency check

Tags: adaptec

I read this article on background consistency check (BCC):
https://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17180/kw/background

I rebooted my system, ran ASM and the log shows alerts that the system has changed and a sense error message. No system change was made during the reboot.

I enabled BCC and performed a verify+fix. This array is RAID6, 2TB and the check has been running for almost 24 hours. I don't think it should take this long.

I tried disabling BCC in ASM but cannot, receiving an alert window saying:

**Operation failed: could not change bcc mode to disabled. The logical device verify task failed to stop because it was not running.
RC:-5:API:0x1fa IOCTL:0x0**

I tried disabling BCC in the CLI and it apparently succeeded:

**C:\adaptec\asm\cmdline>arcconf datascrub 1 off
Controllers found: 1
Command completed successfully.**

But, the log file still shows it scrubbing and ASM still shows the option to **disable** BCC - not enable it again; so it thinks BCC is still enabled.

The log file always shows 0% progress for the scrub and ASM shows no moving icons or anything of the progress. Here's a sample line from the log file:

**localhost Running: RAID 6 scrub - 0%. 0 different sectors. Controller 1, logical device 0**

I get 28 of those lines, over the course of about 7 hours, then I get these lines:

**localhost Running: RAID 6 scrub - 0%. 324,506,182 different sectors. Controller 1, logical device 0**

**localhost Running: RAID 6 scrub - 0%. 0 different sectors. Controller 1, logical device 0**

**localhost Running: RAID 6 scrub - 0%. 0 different sectors. Controller 1, logical device 0**

**localhost Running: RAID 6 scrub - 0%. 324,506,182 different sectors. Controller 1, logical device 0**

Then it repeats with another 28 lines as before.

The array is otherwise working fine. It appears that I may be able to disable BCC only in the array setup upon BIOS boot, before getting into Win7. But, I'm afraid to reboot the system and have something go wrong. I also can't find information on the BIOS boot options, to read up before I have to jump into that.

Any help appreciated.

-Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Update: The scrub finished after 29 hours, no problem found. I then disabled BCC in ASM and it took. So, you cannot change BCC setting while there's a scrub underway. Seems illogical.

That still leaves the same old issue of 0% displayed in the log during the entire scrub process. Also, no progress indication in ASM for scrub. As this controller is long past support, there will be no solution for this issue.